# Reading all files from directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, filesystems

I have a problem reading files from a directory. The path to the diegtory is obtained from tkinter with the `get()` method. But my code   raises this error (the file is exsist in it):

> FileNotFoundError: [Error 2] No such file or directory: 'filename.csv'

Here is the function:

```py
def readf(self):
    for r, d, f in os.walk(self.name_m.get()):
        for filepath in f:
            with open(filepath, 'r') as csvFile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
                m = np.array([])
                for row in reader:
                    m = np.append(m, float(row[0])
```

Comment: Did you check the path is correct ? Try adding `print(f)` before the file open and see if `filename.csv` comes up. After that use `os.path.join` to append r,d,f

Comment: @M.F the path is correct. Its `C:/project/result/csvfiles` looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is normal in :

```
for r, d, f in os.walk(self.name_m.get()):
```

You split the output of os.walk between **r** (which contains base repository), **d** (which contains the sub repositories) and **f** (which contains filenames)

When you do:

```
for filepath in f:
          with open(filepath, 'r') as csvFile:
```

You try to open the filenames in you current work directory and not where they are store.

Do you want to read all the files for a directory and include all the sub-directory or just want all the files in the base directory ?

For the second option the simplest way for you to achieve this goal is to do:

```
import glob
import os

def readf(self):
   for filepath in [fic for fic in glob.glob(os.path.join(self.name_m.get(), '*.csv'))]:
       with open(filepath, 'r') as csvFile:
           reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
           m = np.array([])
              for row in reader:
                 m = np.append(m, float(row[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to stackoverflow! For us to help you best, it's important that you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's tricky to help without knowing what  this `get` method is for example.

That being said, a couple things that might help:

You can use the `glob` function from the builtin `glob` module to get all the files tha tmatch a certain pattern in a directory tree.

```py
import glob

files = glob.glob('/path/to/files/**/*.csv', recursive=True)
```

This is easier than iterating over the directory tree manually.

Further, you can use third party libraries such as pandas to load csv files easier, with a higher level api:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Overall, you would get something like:

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob('/path/to/files/**/*.csv', recursive=True)

file_list = [pd.read_csv(filenamee) for filenamee in files]
```

Or if you want to manipulate each loaded file first, to keep the first column for example or cast to float:

```py
file_list = []
for filename in files:
    res = pd.read_csv(filename)
    res = res.iloc[:, 0] # keep the first column
    res = res.apply(float) # cast to float
    file_list.append(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the full file path, with the root and the directory.

Here's a simple fix to your code:

```
for root, directories, files in os.walk(self.name_m.get()):
    for r in root:
        for d in directories:
            for f in files:
                with open(os.path.join(r,d,f), 'r') as cur_file:
                    if cur_file.read().endswith((".csv")): 
                        reader = cur_file.reader(csvFile)
                        m = np.array([])
                        for row in reader:
                            m = np.append(m, float(row[0])
```

Notice that you are assuming here that you only have `csv` files in that directory (and subdirectories)

So, add the `.endswith()` method to confirm only opening csv files